# Can my standard deviation calculation be made more efficient?

Tags: java, performance, statistics, java-8

I'm curious if my standard deviation method can be made more efficient. By efficient I mean fast, and by fast I mean latency from method call to method return.

Here's the code:

```
public double stdDev(ArrayList<Double> input) {

    double Nrecip   = ( 1.0 / ( input.size()) );
    double sum      = 0.0;
    double average  = 0.0;

    for (Double input : inputs) {
        average += input;
    } average *= Nrecip;

    for (Double input : inputs) {
        sum += ( (input - average)*(input - average) );
    } sum *= Nrecip;

    return Math.sqrt(sum);

}
```

I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: You could do `average += Nrecip*input;`, but that won't make anything faster

Comment: You could use `double` instead of `Double` and use a fraction of the memory.

Comment: Compute `(input - average)` only once instead of twice?

Comment: Use just one for loop and use the fact that `Var(X) = E[ (X-E[X])² ] = E[X²] - (E[X])²`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can calculate the standard deviation in a single pass.  Using a `double[]` would be more efficient as well.

```
public static double stdDev(double... a) {
    double sum = 0;
    double sq_sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        double ai = a[i];
        sum += ai;
        sq_sum += ai * ai;
    }
    double mean = sum / n;
    double variance = sq_sum / n - mean * mean;
    return Math.sqrt(variance);
}
```

This a conversion of this solution [in C here](https://www.strchr.com/standard_deviation_in_one_pass)

Passing the memory once could improve the performance.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks. What does `double... a` mean? I am not familiar with that syntax. Also, I am using `ArrayList<Double>` because this method will often be used on a rolling basis, so using an `ArrayList` allows simple updating. Is the speed loss significant between the two data structures? I thought `ArrayList` had constant time read.

Comment: @d0rmLife ArrayList is a constant time as is the cost of creating `new Double` but the constant factor is higher. Using `double..` is like an array but you can use `double d = stdDev(1,2,3,4,5);` Using a `double[]` can use ~28% of the memory of an `ArrayList<Double>` which can make a difference when you start using up your CPU caches.

Comment: @d0rmLife here is an example of a class which wraps a `double[]` but acts like an ArrayList http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/list/array/TDoubleArrayList.html

Comment: Am I reading this right that you can calculate the sum of all the squares of a population and then the variance = (sq_sum / n) - (mean*mean)? Would it be possible for the variance to be negative?

Comment: @simgineer only if there is a representation error. The square of the averages should always be less than (or the same as) the average of the squares.

Comment: really cool algo and so simple mathematic explanation under the link, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

using [org.apache.commons.math3.stat.descriptive](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.2/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/DescriptiveStatistics.html#getStandardDeviation())

```
public double stdDev(ArrayList<Double> input) { 

    DescriptiveStatistics ds = new DescriptiveStatistics(input.toArray(new Double[0]));

    return ds.getStandardDeviation();

}
```